# .NET program which can be called from ASP.NET and run as a scheduled task

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, webforms, windows-server-2003

I need to write a program which will send out e-mails...

It needs to be set up as a scheduled task in Windows and be called on demand from an ASP.NET website.

I know how to write an executable (and my ASP.NET website is near completion).

I know how to code the program, but I wish to avoid duplicating my code in two places!

My first idea was to code a .exe, set it up as a scheduled task, and call it from the code in the ASP.NET website e.g. button_clicked but I'm not so sure this is a good idea.

**Is there a better way (more secure, but without much more effort)?**

It's an ASP.NET Website Project (not an application) it's not part of a solution - should it have been?.

Comment: What security issues are you concerned about with sending emails via a button in ASP.NET website?

Comment: Why not abstract the code out into a separate assembly you can share between your executable and website.  Then you have no duplicated code.

Comment: You could have the schedule task generate a http request (using curl or a small custom program) to the website, and that could trigger the logic from your website project

Comment: @KarlAnderson no I'm talking about running an exe from ASP.NET

Comment: @GeorgeJohnston Please could you provide more detail as an answer?

Comment: @Brandon Please could you provide more detail as an answer? How would I secure that so that it will not execute if called over the public internet?

Comment: @ChrisCannon for web request approach you could either check the source ip address and constrain to address of local machine or you could make 2 sites in iis that point to the same application, one that's publicly accessible, one that isn't. There's lots of ways to do it

Comment: @DarrenKopp ATM I am leaning more towards this, could you provide an answer, perhaps showing how web.config could be used to restrict access?

Comment: @ChrisCannon It wouldn't be in web.config, it'd have to be in code. You would check either `Request.IsLocal` or `Request.UserHostAddress` and compare to machines IP address, and if it matches, then allow the request to continue, otherwise throw an exception or just return a 403 status code.

Comment: @DarrenKopp Request.IsLocal sounds like a good idea, I'm thinking of using an ashx for this? What to do after successful execution? I'm thinking of setting content type to text and either returning blank file or maybe some useful output, and then returning 200 OK?

Comment: @ChrisCannon that should be fine. Whatever is calling it can basically just ignore the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the GAC on the server, then just abstract the code out of the EXE and into a library assembly.  Add the library DLL to the GAC.  Then reference that DLL from both the EXE and the Web project.

If you don't have access to the GAC you can still do it, just deploy the DLL with the EXE and in your web app's bin.

EDIT

here's how to create a library assembly http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/07/understanding-c-namespaces-and.html

Comment: Sound like a good way to do it, could you provide a link to a tutorial on how to create a DLL?

Answer (score 1):

Have the sending code inside of ASP.NET and have the scheduled task request a password-protected URL on your website (e.g. `/send-mails?pw=jdgdifgnfdhg`). That way you don't need an EXE. You can execute the http request using curl.exe. Super simple.

Comment: If it was an Internet web site I definitely wouldn't have a password in the URL, but mines on an intranet so worth considering because I could run it manually myself if needed. Why curl when you can write a one line Powershell script or even a VbScript? You have to download curl?

Comment: Execute the request any way you want. I'm not familiar with ps or vbs.; A password in the URL is simpler than a simulated login. You can check it using a simple if statement.